# Declaring a function map using "|| {}" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I saw the following syntax in JavaScript that allows you to add functions to an Objects element so you can perform a switch alternative. Consider the following:

```
var insert = insert || {};

 insert.Actor = function (user) {
    //Do Somthing
}
```

This would allow you to do the following:

```
function addUser(type) {

    if (insert[type]) {
            return insert[type](user);
        }
}
```

I like this implementation but I have two questions:

1. What exactly is this statement doing and could i just declare a regular object?

   var insert = insert || {};
2. Besides readability what advantages do I get by using this instead of a regular switch statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What exactly is this statement doing and could i just declare a regular object?

In JS, `foo.bar` results in a reference error if foo is not defined.  `var insert = insert || {};` ensures that `insert` will be an object, so that checks like `if(insert[type])` will work as expected (`insert[type]` will be undefined)

More generally, `||` is the logical OR operator, which works as follows: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.11 if the left hand side expression (`insert` in this case) is a "truthy value" (including objects but not values like `0` or `undefined`), then the value is LHS; otherwise the value is the RHS expression.

> Besides readability what advantages do I get by using this instead of a regular switch statement.

You would have to have many conditionals of the form `if(insert)` in every block of the switch statement.  Using this method, you obviate most of them.

Answer (score 3):

You can add functions to any Object in JavaScript.  The syntax you see just "says" If the object already exists... use it, otherwise, create a new object.

```
var insert = insert || {};
```

The variable `insert` is being set to itself, `||` (OR) being set to `{}` which is the short syntax for a new Object.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert || {};
```

Return the first operant that is true from the left to the right.

This is a "OR" operator. In Javascript a "OR" operator dose not simply return true/false boolean value. This is just a short cut to say if insert is not defined, define it as an object.

Answer (score 0):

1. It really depends on whether you have a reason to believe that `insert` has already been declared in that scope or not and whether it's the same `insert` you want or not. Obviously if `insert` has been defined somewhere else and doesn't do what you want it to do, then this syntax isn't helpful, because it's going to set `insert` in your scope to the `insert` that's already defined somewhere else.
2. Versus using a `switch` statement, it's a style preference. That's really all it amounts to. You have to ask yourself, "Who will be reading this, and what will be most helpful to them in understanding what this does?"

Answer (score 0):

```
var insert=insert||{};
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (!insert) var insert={};
```

(if the insert object doesn't exist, create it)

The first expression just makes the code shorter.

This is often used in modular scripts, as any module could initialize the insert object which will then be reused by the other modules.